# Compare logs without timestamp

Tags: diff

I have a lot of logs I would like to compare. The problem is, that the first few characters in a line are a timestamp. How can I compare logs, ignoring timestamps.

For example, these two should be the same:

```
httpd:debug:64.715:rutWan_getIpOrPppObjectByIfname:2124:looking for eth1
httpd:debug:64.717:rutWan_getIpOrPppObjectByIfname:2134:found WanIPConnection object
httpd:debug:64.719:odl_setObjectExternal:463:starting external set of WANIPConnection iidStack={3,1,6}
httpd:debug:64.719:rcl_wanIpConnObject:178:Entered
httpd:debug:64.719:rutCfg_tearDownWanIpConnection:365:Enter.
httpd:debug:64.719:rutWl2_getL2LinkObj:122:Enter.
```

and:

```
httpd:debug:328.628:rutWan_getIpOrPppObjectByIfname:2124:looking for eth1
httpd:debug:328.630:rutWan_getIpOrPppObjectByIfname:2134:found WanIPConnection object
httpd:debug:328.632:odl_setObjectExternal:463:starting external set of WANIPConnection iidStack={3,1,6}
httpd:debug:328.632:rcl_wanIpConnObject:178:Entered
httpd:debug:328.632:rutCfg_tearDownWanIpConnection:365:Enter.
httpd:debug:328.632:rutWl2_getL2LinkObj:122:Enter.
```

**EDIT:** The httpd part can also differ, since its the name of the process that called the function from a library.

Comment: Can you confirm where the timestamp is in these snippets, have you truncated them or is it the column after "httpd:debug"?

Comment: @Dayvo the column after httpd:debug...but httpd can also be consoled or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` to get rid of the timestamp "column"

```
cat logfile | cut -d":" -f1,2,4- > logfile_notimestamp
```

if you do this for both files, you can easily compare them using diff.

Comment: `-f` means fields. it is a list of columns (divided by `:`) which you want to keep in your output. If you want to get rid of httpd, remove `1,` from the line

Comment: that would work, thanks...but I thought if there is a way, without creating new files all the time just for comparing

Comment: `diff <(cut -d":" -f1,2,4- <FILENAME>) <(cut -d":" -f1,2,4- <FILENAME>)`